# What is this `impl<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J> Default for (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J)`

Tags: rust

Found this in the default trait documentation and wondering what it is:

```rs
impl<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J> Default for (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J)
where
    A: Default,
    B: Default,
    C: Default,
    D: Default,
    E: Default,
    F: Default,
    G: Default,
    H: Default,
    I: Default,
    J: Default,
```

Is this important in any way?

Reference: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html#impl-Default-63

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, Default trait is implemented for any tuple struct with 10 elements where each element implements Default. This is ugly, but I suppose there is no better way to express this in the language. It is repeated for other number of elements in the same file too.

I can't name any, but I have seen such generic definition repetitions elsewhere in Rust std lib. Later some were expressed better with new language features. You can probably find other examples by searching macro_rules within the standard library source code.

Edit:
If one day `Variadic generics` comes to Rust, it would provide an idiomatic way to implement a trait for arbitrary tuples.

See: [About variadics in Rust](https://gist.github.com/PoignardAzur/aea33f28e2c58ffe1a93b8f8d3c58667)

Comment: Oh, makes sense. Will do some digging.

Comment: Assuming there are no `#[doc(hidden)]` implementations on tuples, you can see these usages on the [`tuple`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.tuple.html) Rust docks. The standard library traits which do this are `Debug`, `Default`, `Hash`, `PartialOrd`, `Ord`, `PartialEq`, and `Eq`. Notably, these are all traits which must visit each member unless otherwise specified to perform their role so it makes sense that they would follow the same design structure.

Comment: there are a lot of types from the std lib that have some ugly impl like that, like owned slices, they have Default implemented for lenght 0 to 10 in a similar very ugly way